# Determine if an image is b/w or colored in Java

Tags: java, image, colors

Is there an efficient way to determine if an image is in greyscale or in color? By efficient I don't mean reading all the pixels of the image and looking for every single RGB value then.

For example, in Python there is a function inside the Imaging library called 'getcolors' that returns a hash of pairs `{ (R G B) -> counter }` for the whole image and I just have to iterate over that hash looking for only one entry in color.

**UPDATE**:

For future readers of this post: I implemented a solution reading pixel by pixel the image (as @npinti suggested on his link) and it seems to be fast enough for me (you should take your time implementing it, won't take you more than 10 minutes). It seems the Python implementation of the pixel by pixel way is really bad (inneficient and slow).

Comment: How would you expect the Python "getcolors" to be implemented?

Comment: And how do you think that library in Python is working? *Efficient* and *easy to use* isn't the same thing, you can write such a function yourself, and if you use higher-level languages like Scala, it'll take 3 lines of code.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I never said _easy to use_, I know they aren't  the same thing. I'm just asking if you know any library of function that extract this type of information at once from an image.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It may be implemented looking for every single pixel oooor maybe (what I'm looking for) someone took the time to parse some kind of raw bytes or data on the image to do so.

Comment: @josej30, to my knowledge no such function exist.  Also you may need to consider that for JPEG images several hues of the same color may be present due to compression artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703624/how-to-determine-if-an-image-java-awt-image-is-bw-with-no-color) previous SO post should provide helpful.

Comment: +1, it does and does not answer the question - does not, because the author didn't wanted to do it this way and does - because this is the only way ;-)

Comment: Yeah as @TomaszNurkiewicz said, I already checked that post and that's exactly the way I don't want to do it but I'll dig more into it then.