# how to detect image is graycscale or not

Tags: java

there was an accepted answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703624/how-do-you-determine-if-an-image-java-awt-image-is-bw-with-no-color) . It said if value R == G == B then it's a grayscale image. 
I tried to compare first pixel and it did the trick. But, i think a color image has possibilities to be having a same RGB value for some pixel, especialy in first pixel.

i dont wanna do for-loop to check all pixel, it would spend more times. 
so, is there other way to check the image is in grayscale or not ?
or, is there getter method that i can use to get this information from its metadata ?

Comment: There is no built-in method for this and you can't do this without looping through all pixels and checking this for yourself.

Comment: A *real* gray-scale image should be saved with different flags (mainly a different colorspace). How is the image loaded/generated?

Comment: Than take every fourth pixel

Comment: If you *really* cannot use the color space information of the image (for example you want to detect greyscale images saved as RGB), then Arrays.equals() on the byte array for each channel can save you the loop... If you can extract the three byte arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure but have you tried?

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIo.read(new File("imageName"));
ColorSpace colorSpace = image.getColorModel().getColorSpace();
int type = colorSpace.getType();
if (type = ColorSpace.CS_GRAY ){
    //...
}
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.html for colorspace

Comment: i tried your code,but i use ColorSpace.TYPE_GRAY instead. And it works. thank you, sir ! :)

Comment: wow - i'm really glad i could help out - honsetly i havent tried it before... so great then!!